# Random moving animation using prototypal inheritance pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an animation that each list item will float randomly inside its wrapper. I'm trying to put together using prototypal inheritance pattern but it's not doing it. There are a couple of places that I think it may be cause to the problem but I need some advice to proceed.

```
function Menu($item) {
    this.item = $item;
};

Menu.prototype.makeNewPosition = function ($container) {
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
};


Menu.prototype.move = function () {
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var newq = this.makeNewPosition(value.parent());
        value.animate({
          top: newq[0],
          left: newq[1]
        }, 400, function() {
          this.move();
        });
    });
};

var $menu = new Menu($('.nav li'));
$menu.move();
```

Within `move` function, there is `animate` and within this I'm calling `move` again to run the animation indefinitely. If it's calling itself in prototypal structure, can it be called using `this`?

Not also sure about the use of `$.each` within `move` function.

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzmh63xb/12/)

Comment: any console errors to report?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: value.parent is not a function` is in console.

Comment: I see that now. I guess I need to wrap `value` as jQuery object to access `parent()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version

- uses self instead of that - I use `that`, most people use `self` - I'm different :p
- set `$value = $(value)` ... DRY

.

```
function Menu($item) {
    this.item = $item;
};

Menu.prototype.makeNewPosition = function ($container) {
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
};


Menu.prototype.move = function () {
    var self = this;
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var $value = $(value);
        var newq = self.makeNewPosition($value.parent());
        $value.animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, 400, function() {
            self.move();
        });
    });
};

var $menu = new Menu($('.nav li'));
$menu.move();
```

> original answer below - which contains explanation of changes

Here's ALL the errors fixed, not just the first

```
function Menu($item) {
    this.item = $item;
};

Menu.prototype.makeNewPosition = function ($container) {
    var h = $container.height() - 50;
    var w = $container.width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];
};


Menu.prototype.move = function () {
    var that = this; // added that because the this isn't the this you want in the $.each function
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var newq = that.makeNewPosition($(value).parent());
        //         ^^^^                 ^^     ^
        //         that instead of this
        //                             $(value) instead of value
        $(value).animate({
      // ^^     ^
      // $(value) instead of value
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, 400, function() {
            that.move();
          //^^^^ another this to that change
        });
    });
};

var $menu = new Menu($('.nav li'));
$menu.move();
```

There's ways to clean up the code even more, but these changes should get you working at least

The working changes to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wzmh63xb/16/

Comment: Thanks, it now does the animation but it only runs once. is `this.move()` the right way to self invoke move function?

Comment: damn, change `this.move` to `that.move` - answer and fiddle updated

Comment: Ah, got that now. Will choose your answer in 3 minutes. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, that's really really annoying :D

Comment: I'll remove my answer as this is the full one, but I would also set $(value) to another variable so it gets reused instead of instantiated twice

Comment: @JaromandaX. sorry for same answer. but i didn't see your answer.

Comment: I'll change my answer with that @Michael

Answer (score 0):

There is your mistakes. Try this. it is working.

```
Menu.prototype.move = function () {
     var self = this;
    $.each(this.item, function(index, value) {
        var newq = self.makeNewPosition($(value).parent());

        $(value).animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, 400, function() {
        self.move();
    });
    });
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sherali/wzmh63xb/14/)